# Getting the MAC address of the device- when wifi is off

Tags: android, android-wifi, mac-address, wifimanager

I am finding the MAC address of the Android Device using the following code:

```
WifiManager manager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo info = manager.getConnectionInfo();
String address = info.getMacAddress());
```

But in this case I am unable to get the MAC address when the Wifi is off. How can I get the MAC address of the Android Device even when WIFI is off.

Thanks

Comment: You can not get MAC Address if the WiFi is off, in that case you can use DEVICE ID which is again unique for all devices.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Why not enable the Wifi momentarily until you get the MAC address and then disable it once you are done getting the MAC address?

*Of course, doing this is if getting the MAC address is absolutely important.*

**UNTESTED CODE**

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

if(wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) {
    // WIFI ALREADY ENABLED. GRAB THE MAC ADDRESS HERE
    WifiInfo info = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
    String address = info.getMacAddress();
} else {
    // ENABLE THE WIFI FIRST
    wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);

    // WIFI IS NOW ENABLED. GRAB THE MAC ADDRESS HERE
    WifiInfo info = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
    String address = info.getMacAddress();
}
```

You will need these permission setup in the Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

I am not entirely sure if the `UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS` permission is necessary in this case. Please try it out before deciding to keep it.

Comment: I think you should not disable wifi if it is already enabled. It also looks that UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS is not necessary.

Comment: UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS permission is only granted to system apps

Comment: Why do you need to turn the device's WIFI on to get its MAC address?

Comment: @MichaelLiberman: When I had to use it the first time round, most tutorials advised that WiFi be turned on. Not necessarily connected to a network, but enabled nonetheless. Also, I got mixed results with WiFi disabled on different devices. So, I just stick to it. Also (_again_), as mentioned before the code, it was untested. I was away from my office PC when I put this in. The logic was always right though.

Comment: @MichaelLiberman: Found an Android Blog (_it was buried deep in my bookmarks somewhere_) which states the same. [Identifying App Installations](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html). Scroll down the section titled **Mac Address**. It essentially says the same. Hope this helps. ;-)