# Send a direct message to MAC address of raspberry pi from Android?

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, mac-address

I have implemented a simple application on *Raspberry Pi* where I am able to open a car or pull down it's windows.

Now I would like to create a very primitive Android application that would simply sent a message to the **MAC address** of the *Raspberry Pi*.

Can I achieve something like that? If yes then how?

Comment: If you don't want to implement your own protocol stack, then you need IP for data transfer. (UDP, TCP)

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14949872/getting-the-mac-address-of-the-device-when-wifi-is-off

Comment: did you even read my question ?